# Library.add is not a function error

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor, prototype

I am trying to execute this code:

```
var addButton = document.querySelector("#add");
var searchButton = document.querySelector("#search");
var titleInput = document.querySelector("#title");

function Book(title) {
    this.title = title;
}

function Library() {
    this.books = [];
}

Library.prototype.add = function() {
    this.add = function(book) {
        this.books.push(book);
    };
}

var library = new Library();

//Library UI
var libraryUI = {
    //Add a new book
    addBook: function() {
        var listItem = libraryUI.createNewBook(titleInput.value);
        Library.add(listItem);
        console.log(Library.books);
    },
    //Create a new book
    createNewBook: function(title) {
        var book = new Book(title);
        return book;
    }
};

addButton.addEventListener("click", libraryUI.addBook);
```

The HTML is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Library App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Personal Library</h1>

        <label for="title">Title: </label>
        <input type="text" id="title">

        <button id="add">Add</button>
        <button id="search">Search</button>

        <p id="display"></p>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is press the addButton and the onclick will run the addBook function under the libraryUI object. The title of the book, in an input field, will then be used to create an object with the title of the book in it. I want to add that book to a list of books (an array) in an instance of Library. When I try to do so with the following code, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Library.add is not a function". I thought that Library.add *is* a function.

I added:

```
var library = new Library();
```

because I thought I had forgotten to create an iteration of Library, but I still came up with the exact same error. Please help. :)

Comment: Typo? `Library.add(listItem);` is attempting to invoke `add()` as a method of the `Library` constructor rather than of the `library` instance -- `library.add(listItem);` and `console.log(library.books);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var addButton = document.querySelector("#add");
var searchButton = document.querySelector("#search");
var titleInput = document.querySelector("#title");

function Book(title) {
    this.title = title;
}

function Library() {
    this.books = [];
}

Library.prototype.add = function(book) {
   this.books.push(book);
}

var library = new Library();

//Library UI
var libraryUI = {
    //Add a new book
    addBook: function() {
        var listItem = libraryUI.createNewBook(titleInput.value);
        library.add(listItem);
        console.log(library.books);
    },
    //Create a new book
    createNewBook: function(title) {
        var book = new Book(title);
        return book;
    }
};

addButton.addEventListener("click", libraryUI.addBook);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Library App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Personal Library</h1>

        <label for="title">Title: </label>
        <input type="text" id="title">

        <button id="add">Add</button>
        <button id="search">Search</button>

        <p id="display"></p>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Shouldn't it be `library.add` instead of `Library.add`?

Also: why:

`Library.prototype.add = function() {
    this.add = function(book) {
        this.books.push(book);
    };
}`

instead of:

`Library.prototype.add = function(book) {
    this.books.push(book);
}`

?

If I change `Library.add` to `library.add` and `console.log(library.books)` I think this does what you want.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I just started learning about constructor functions so in my haste to practice I didn't even notice my invalid syntax.